# How to export data from Gridview or Database to Excel with LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, database, excel, linq, gridview

I used this code for import data from Excel Sheet into database and now i want to do the opposite.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pach = @"D:\C# Projects\P.xlsx";
        var exlData = new ExcelQueryFactory(pach);
        var data = from x in exlData.Worksheet<excelData>("Sheet1")
                   select x;
        DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            db.tbl_PrsInfos.InsertOnSubmit(new tbl_PrsInfo
            {
                Id = d.Id,
                FullName = d.FullName,
                Personnely = d.Personnely,
                CodeBank = d.CodeBank,
                Bank = d.Bank,
                Email = d.Email,
                State = d.State,
            });
        }
        db.SubmitChanges();
        dgv_prs_add.DataSource = from show in db.tbl_PrsInfos select show;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the `LinqToExcel` library which is a read only interface for Excel sheets.

To write an Excel file you have a few options:

- Use a third party library to write an Excel file without requiring Excel to be installed (for example the library from Aspose)
- Write a CSV file using in-built C# file writing functions and open the CSV in Excel
- Use office automation to create an Excel file programmatically. This requires Excel to be installed.